# PHP:: How to call static method (or property) from extended class?

Tags: php, oop, static

I have **Model** class, and **Model_Something** class. **Model_Something** have static property ( table name ).

I want to access **Model_Something** static property from **Model** class. 
But it try to find it in **Model** class and give me exception:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: 
Access to undeclared static property: Model::$_collection_name
```

I try to access it in this way:

```
self::$some_property;
```

How to get it?

Comment: Please include declaration of `Model_Something` and `Model` class. Which class extends which?

Comment: You might want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349637/correct-implementation-of-virtual-functions-in-php)

Comment: If the parent class needs to access a property of a subclass, then the property probably should be available in all subclasses. Why not move it to the parent class instead? That also has the advantage that the parent does not need to know implementation details of the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not access a property in a class which does not exist and depend on it being present in the child. The parent cannot/should not know what a child does, it needs to be the other way around. So first, declare the property in the parent as well, so the parent can access it in any case. The child may then *override* the value of the property. To make sure you're always accessing the property of the executing class, you need *late static binding*, which you get by using `static` instead of `self`:

```
static::$some_property;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: As in real life, a parent should never depend on its children ;)

Comment: Cause you know they'll just run out and leave you alone the moment they turn 18. ;)

Answer (score -1):

**parent::$some_property;** it will make your code less dependable as if you change your class name you have to change here also if you use class name.

Comment: Than **self::$some_property;** else **Class_name::$some_property;** if the property of the is overridden by the child class. say you have class a(with property x), class b(with property x) extends class a and class c(with property x) extends class b and you want to access property x of class c than use self::$a and you want to access property x of class b than use b::$a